# Why the shader doesn't appear in onDraw?

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es

I have encountered this peculiar behaviour in`View.onDraw(Canvas canvas).

When I execute the following code my shader works as expected:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);
   mGraphPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), 0xFFEEB422, 0x00EEB422,
       Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
   canvas.drawPath(path, mGraphPaint);

   // Rest of code
}
```

[image]

Notice however, that an object for LinearGradient is created in each call.

The obvious solution:

```
private LinearGradient mShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), 0xFFEEB422, 0x00EEB422,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);
   mGraphPaint.setShader(mShader);
   canvas.drawPath(path, mGraphPaint);

   // Rest of code
}
```

[image]

However, the second approach does not seem to work and my question is *Why?*

Comment: call `mShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, ...` inside `onSizeChanged`

Comment: @pskink WOW... this works great, thanks. The question as to _Why_ it doesn't work in the second approach is still a mystery to me. :)

Comment: because `getHeight()` returns 0

Comment: @pskink Never would have guessed! Thanks!

Comment: Convert it to an answer then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, to sublime the comments into an answer:

The method `getHeight()` returns 0, before `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`is called for the first time, so the `LinearGradient` object is created with 0 height - thus it does not appear.